# PInvoke method contained in a native structure

Tags: c#, api, struct, pinvoke

I am trying to re-create some C++ sample API usage code in C#.
It's looking like I might need to create a C++/CLI wrapper to make the API functions accessible to the managed world, but I'd like to avoid that if possible. The API library itself only has a single exported function: `data_api_func_tab`.

This is what the C++ API usage looks like:

```cpp
//
// .h file 
// 
typedef struct _DATA_API_FUNC_TAB {
    short   (*api_init)();
    // ... lots of other methods ...

} DATA_API_FUNC_TAB

extern  "C"  typedef short  (* MAPIINIT)(short);
// ... lots of other methods ...

#undef  EXTERN
#ifdef  _MAIN
#define EXTERN
#else
#define EXTERN  extern
#endif

EXTERN  MAPIINIT ncm_api_init;
// ... lots of other methods ...

public:
    UCHAR SomeVariable;
    void SomeMethod( arguments );

//
// .cpp file
//  
/// Constructor
CWidgetDataApi::CWidgetDataApi()
{
    SomeVariable = 0;

    m_hInstHdl = ::LoadLibrary(_T(".\\NATIVEAPI.dll"));
    if( NULL != m_hInstHdl )
    {
        DATA_API_FUNC_TAB* p_data_api_func_tab =
            (DATA_API_FUNC_TAB*) ::GetProcAddress(m_hInstHdl, "data_api_func_tab");
        SomeVariable = 1;

        if( p_data_api_func_tab == NULL )
        {
            ::FreeLibrary(m_hInstHdl);
            m_hInstHdl = NULL;
            SomeVariable = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            api_init = (MAPINIT) p_data_api_func_tab->api_init;
            // ... lots of other methods ...

            short Ret = api_init(index);
        }
    }
}

/// Method
void CWidgetDataApi::SomeMethod( arguments )
{
   // ... Makes use of the various other methods ...
}

//
// Usage in another class
//
DataAPI = new CWidgetDataApi;

if( DataAPI->SomeVariable == 1 )
{ 
    DataAPI->SomeMethod( arguments );  
    ...
}
```

Since I can't use reflection on the native library (not to mention it would be slow), PInvoke seems to be the only way in.

I have recreated the appropriate structures in C# and tried the following PInvoke signatures,

```cpp
[DllImport("NATIVEAPI.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern struct data_api_func_tab { };

[DllImport("NATIVEAPI.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern short api_init([In, Out] ref _DATA_API_FUNC_TAB data_api_func_tab);
```

but they produce the exception

> Unable to find an entry point named '... whatever I try...' in NATIVEAPI.dll

I've searched around for a way to do this but only seem to find unmanaged to C++/CLI solutions. Is what I am attempting to do even possible (given that the individual methods contained in the structure are not exported)?

Comment: Define the struct completly in C# and only declare the native function to be imported.

Comment: @Felix there is no function to be imported

Comment: The data_api_func_tab() declaration requires CallingConvention.Cdecl and ExactSpelling = true since the function name isn't decorated.  Return type is IntPtr, use Marshal.PtrToStructure to recover the structure.  Declare the app_init member of the structure as a delegate, it needs [UnmanagedFunctionPointer] to declare it Cdecl.

Comment: @Hans No. `data_api_func_tab` is a data export rather than a function export.

Comment: `api_init` is a function.

Comment: @FelixK. I think David's point is that DllImport can only return functions, whereas `data_api_func_tab` is a data type (a structure of pointers to functions). I believe the API is obfuscated in this way on purpose - to discourage anyone from playing around with things that can break their expensive equipment or hurt someone. If you don't know the exact layout and contents of the structure, you can't call its functions.

Comment: @FelixK. Indeed it is. But it's not exported by the DLL in the standard way. You have to get a pointer to a struct and dig the function pointer out from that struct

Comment: Aye, just having some trouble with the digging part now. I will consider posting a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty far out API. Instead of exporting functions, the library exports the address of a struct containing function pointers. Notice how the C++ code call `GetProcAddress` and then interprets the result as a pointer to a struct and not as is more common, as a pointer to a function.

From the documentation of `GetProcAddress`, with my emphasis:

> Retrieves the address of an exported function or **variable** from the specified dynamic-link library (DLL).

You cannot use `DllImport` to access this library's export because `DllImport` is for functions rather than variables.

Here's what you must do:

1. Use `LoadLibrary` to load the DLL and obtain a module handle as an `IntPtr`.
2. Call `GetProcAddress` to obtain the address of the struct.
3. Use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to get a managed struct containing the function pointers.
4. Use `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` for each member of the struct to obtain a delegate which you can then call.
5. When you are done with the library unload it by calling `FreeLibrary`. You can omit this step if you are happy to wait until the process terminates and the system unloads automatically.

Assuming you can obtain p/invoke signatures for `LoadLibrary` and friends, the code looks like this:

```
// declare the structure of function pointers

struct DATA_API_FUNC_TAB
{
    IntPtr api_init;
    // more function pointers here
}

....

// load the DLL, and obtain the structure of function pointers

IntPtr lib = LoadLibrary(@"full\path\to\dll");
if (lib == IntPtr.Zero)
    throw new Win32Exception();
IntPtr funcTabPtr = GetProcAddress(lib, "data_api_func_tab");
if (funcTabPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
    throw new Win32Exception();
DATA_API_FUNC_TAB funcTab = (DATA_API_FUNC_TAB)Marshal.PtrToStructure(funcTabPtr, typeof(DATA_API_FUNC_TAB));

....

// declare the delegate types, note the calling convention

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate short api_init_delegate();

....

// obtain a delegate instance

api_init_delegate api_init = (api_init_delegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(funcTab.api_init, typeof(api_init_delegate));

....

// finally we can call the function

short retval = api_init();
```

It's plausible that the marshaller is capable of creating the delegate for you. In which case the struct would be:

```
struct DATA_API_FUNC_TAB
{
    api_init_delegate api_init;
    // more delegates here
}
```

In which case the `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` step would obviously not be necessary, the marshaller having already performed it on your behalf.

I've not tested any of this code, just typed it into the browser. No doubt there are a few wrinkles, but this code is intended more as a guide than as code that you could use directly.

Comment: It's working up until I try to `GetDelegateForFunctionPointer()`. I'm missing something. Note the C++ code where it defines the arguments and return type: `extern  "C"  typedef short  (* MAPIINIT)(short);` That part isn't in my structure (only the return type and function name). I get 'best overloaded method match ... contains some invalid arguments' when trying to specify the function contained in my struct, because it is not a pointer.

Comment: I cannot guess what your code is. Regarding `MAPIINIT` and `ncm_api_init`, they only appear in two lines of the question and are not referenced by the C++ code that does something.

Comment: Updated my question. I had left out the EXTERN / extern define statements. I wasn't sure if they were relevant, but it seems they are.

Comment: No, I don't think that they are relevant. They are unrelated to the calls to `GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`. I answered what was in front of me. I think you understand what is going on here. You are skilled in both languages. I suggest that you keep working at this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've accepted because your answer has taken me almost all the way there. If I can't figure it out, I might make a new question.

Comment: That's probably for the best. Then you can include the new code and it can be focused on that. Thanks.